# C programme the first value of a three dimension table

Tags: c, arrays

A simple code like this,

```
int arr[3][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
printf("%d\n", *(arr));
```

I thought the output would be the first value of table, 1, but gcc returns me a garbage value.

Can anyone explain the difference between multiple dimension table and simple table?

Comment: Do you get `warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *'`? (Which I would not call 'garbage'.)

Comment: arr[0][0] will give you 1, arr[0][1] == 2 and so on.  But what interesting about this is that arr[0][3] == 4, AND arr[1][0] == 4.

Comment: @ryyker i printed all the elements and the last 5 are all 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the address of the first row of the array, which is also the address of the first element of the entire array.

`*(arr)` is equal to `arr[0]`

Therefore you are trying to print an address and should use a %p printf specifier.

Comment: That is, arr is a pointer to a pointer to an int. `*arr` would be a pointer to the first row array (elements 0,0, 0,1, 0,2). You can either look at `**arr`, or (more clearly) `arr[0][0]`.

Comment: @self - How is it incorrect. Just a copy'n'paste job

Comment: @EdHeal What exactly should it mean? You are printing out an unsigned integral value as a signed integer. Try using the pointer type-specifier `"%p"` or at least unsigned integer type-specifier `"%u"`.

Comment: @EdHeal I don't know what your point was, but you print the address with %p.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the supplied code. The poster supplied the code so that answer is the one given not `arr[0]` as demonstrated

Comment: @EdHeal Ed, I'm not exactly sure where the confusion comes from, but here, I hope this following link helps: http://codepad.org/2S1TJ71w `*(arr)` is the same as `arr[0]` just like the *self* had said. It is just that, they both aren't an integer, rather a pointer to an integer, a pointer that holds the address of the very first element in that array `arr`, which happens to be the address of that `1`.

Comment: @self clear. because it is two dimension, *(arr) is only the address of arr[0], and *(*(arr)) would be the value of arr[0]. thanks a lot!